# How to add space between datasets in ng2 doughnut chart

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have created an ng2 doughnut chart, but I am unable to add space between the data sets which is shown in the image[image],

I have tried by adding

```
    layout: {
      padding: 50
    },
```

but it didn't work, maybe what I have tried is wrong, can anyone help me with this.

Comment: can you add it to stackblitz?

Answer (score 1):

You can add space between data in doughnut chart by adding **borderWidth** to dataset

```
{
  data: this.data,
  borderWidth: 15
}
```